# ERROR: No matching distribution for tflite_support_nightly

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When i run the command on colab :

```
!pip install tflite_support_nightly
```

i get this error :
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite_support_nightly (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite_support_nightly

I m using: tf 2.12.0
python 3.10.12
any help?

i changed tf to 2.11.0/2.10.0
and python version to 3.9 and 3.8

Answer (score 1):

It's an hyphen `-`. Not an under-score `_`. Check this - [pypi - tflite-support-nightly](https://pypi.org/project/tflite-support-nightly/#:%7E:text=%3A%3A%20Python%20Modules-,Project%20description,TFLite%20models%20onto%20various%20platforms.)

```
pip install tflite-support-nightly
```